# rspec access new type as variable

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, keynote

By https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure, we can define a new type. Currently, I am using `keynote`(MVP for rails), so there is a new type: `presenter` if I define

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

However, if I do something like

```
expect(presenter).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
```

rspec reports

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `presenter'
```

But as we know,

```
expect(view).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
```

Here `view` is a variable in rspec. How to make `presenter` the same way as `view` or `controller`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add metadata for custom directories like so:

`RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.define_derived_metadata(:file_path => Regexp.new('/spec/presenters/')) do |metadata|
    metadata[:type] = :presenter
  end
end`

I'm not sure what you actually are trying to achieve though. What would you expect the presenter variable you reference above to be exactly? If you want to mock or stub objects you are best off being very specific about what those objects are.